# Can we use HttpResponse object only to keep session management between server and device in Android?

Tags: android, session, httpresponse

Can we use only HttpResponse object to keep all session management between server and device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that would work as the session id needs to be sent back to the server from the device (the client) upon subsequent communications.   You would get the session ID from the server upon the initial communication (login?) and this would be passed back to the device in the HttpResponse in the form of JSON, XML, Etc.  Then, you'll want to pass that session ID to the server with all your HTTP requests.  This can be done in the header of the response.  You can have the server check that the session is still alive and respond with an error code if it is not.

Comment: Thanks. I want to ask one more thing. Can server place and manage cookies on client side if client is communicating with server by using HttpGet and HttpPost requests and without using WebView...???

Comment: It wouldn't be a cookie per say.  What you wouldn't need to do is handle it in another creative way.  Maybe via the SharedPreference class.  But, no.  Android does not natively handle HTTP cookies.